# Android: mkdir() failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, mkdir

I've been trying to get a file storage system on and android phone to run. However, I've encountered the following problem:

```
static File dataFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

...

```
static File userDataFolder = new File(dataFolder, "triathlon");
```

...

```
File dayFolder = new File(userDataFolder, folderName);
if(!dayFolder.exists()){
    boolean result = dayFolder.mkdir();
    if (!result){
        Log.d("dayFolder creation", "failed");
    }
}
```

where folderName is a string representing the current date.

This is the error message:

```
W/System.err: mkdir failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /storage/emulated/0/triathlon/2016-05-23
```

I have added the permissions to write and read from external storage.
Whats is up and how can I fix this?

Comment: What SDK are you targeting? Maybe you need runtime permissions (Lollipop and up)

Comment: That is a valid point, I'm targeting SDK 23, so Android 6.0. I'll check that out, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Yup, that was the fault. Please write your comment as an answer, and you'll get the answer checkmark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
boolean result = dayFolder.mkdir();
```

use

```
boolean result = dayFolder.mkdirs();
```

`.mkdirs()` will create all necessary parent directories.

One or more parent directories might not exist so you can't create a directory using `mkdir()`, so you need `mkdirs()`.

Comment: That made the error message go away. Sadly, it still returns false, so it did not create the directory.

Comment: If you are using SDK 23 or higher, you should check for runtime permissions first, see https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html